# How can I provide intellisense in custom MVC html helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-helpers

I am making a custom MVC html helper that is similar in many ways to the built in ActionLink helper. I noticed that the built in ActionLink helper has intellisense for actionName and controllerName parameters which I find very useful. My question is how can I provide intellisense in a custom html helper I am writing which also has actionName and controllerName parameters? Here is my helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString IconLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string glyphName, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{
   // Implementation
}
```

Is there an attribute of some sort I can use to make intellisense apply to certain parameters? What am I missing?

Here is the video of the intellisense displaying available controller actions for actionName parameter: http://screencast.com/t/xWtaBYnp

Comment: As in the text telling you what the method is doing?

Comment: No as in providing suggestion for available controller and action names. The built in one gives you a list of available controllers and actions in your site.

Comment: did you put your method to right namespace?

Comment: All my helper extensions are placed in System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace which is where all built in helpers are located...

Comment: your intelisense does not show up at all, or you want to add a comment for each of parameters for your function?

Comment: @Robert I updated the original post with a link to a video of what I would like to achieve. Here is the video once more: http://screencast.com/t/xWtaBYnp

Comment: is that a re-sharper or just a normal visual studio intelisense, cause i found this article http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/07/providing-intellisense-navigation-and-more-for-custom-helpers-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: @Robert I think you are correct it is Resharper feature. I apologize for not realizing that, I've had Resharper for too long now...

Comment: no problem @Marko. i'm glad i could help.